# Problems with Epilog and Show

Tags: plotting

Writing:

```
p1 = ParametricPlot[{t, t}, {t, -1, 1}, 
     Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[{-1, -1}], Point[{1, 1}]}];

p2 = ParametricPlot[{1, t}, {t, 1, 2}, 
     Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[{1, 1}], Point[{1, 2}]}];

Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> All]
```

I get:

[image]

and I do not understand why only the first two points are plotted.

Thank you!

Comment: Answer is very simple,You don't read the help about `Show` ->`Possible Issues` ?

Comment: As explained in the linked thread, what you are seeing here is a matter of precedence, so only `Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[{-1, -1}], Point[{1, 1}]}` gets applied. Better to put `Epilog` in `Show[]` instead: `Show[p1, p2, Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}]}, PlotRange -> All]`